# Watson Assistant: Can I define Intent using Entities in the Examples?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

How to I create an `#Intent` which looks something like this:

> How much is a `@ProductType`?

Whereas the `@ProductType` is an simple **Entity** which consists of:

```
Soft Drinks: Coke, Pepsi, Sprite, Fanta
Fruits: Apple, Banana, Watermelon
```

I tried adding an Intent with above settings, but it doesn't seem to work. Is such ability natively supported in IBM Watson? Or otherwise, do I need to manually handle in the Dialog, using Conditions and stuffs? Please kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

The training is based on regular language and typical sentences or phrases. So `@ProductType` is not what you want in the phrase, but any of the fruits or drinks.

By defining the entities, Watson Assistant later learns the connection and to identify the entities and intents.

To get started, you define the intents and entities. Both can be imported from lists. Then you add the dialog which references the different types.

Comment: Oh, is that correct? Does Watson really "learn" the connections later on it's own? That means, later it will automatically know the "newly added" "additional" entries in the Entity? (Thanks)

Comment: Yup. And if a user later on asks for the price of a pear, WA would know or learn that it is another product type, most likely a fruit... You may see that when you change something that Watson is retraining (learning)

Comment: Well, that'd be the excellent approach if it really does that way. I'll try as you mentioned. Hope it really works. (Meanwhile, before I've confirmed that, please let me hold on with the acceptance of that answer.) Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

This blog should give insight to all the ways to train an entity and how it is used within intents. 
https://medium.com/ibm-watson/all-about-entities-dictionaries-and-patterns-with-watson-assistant-part-1-5ef7254df76b
There are a number of possible pipelines you can choose from.
 1. Indirect references: this is the preferred method. 
Use natural language in your intent training data. "I want to buy a pear"
Watson will automatically see the other values you have related to pear and use those as intent training as well. This will be the fastest and simplest way to manage your data
 2. Direct references: this should only be used if absolutely necessary
Directly reference the entity in your intent data. "I want to buy an @pear"
Nothing is done in the UI to tell you this works, but it does. This tells Watson the entity is a very important term and will increase the weight, as well as reference all synonyms with high weight. This is more effort for you to go through your entire workspace and relabel everything this way, hence why it is not recommended unless absolutely necessary. By doing this, you also tell watson that when the system sees various fruits without the @ symbol, to ignore them as entities which is not ideal
3. Contextual entities. This is highlighting them like in your screenshot.
Note the UI has been updated so there is no an annotation mode instead of just highlighting. This builds a model around the entity, and is good for things like names or locations, but not necessary for a small list of items like crayons in a box, or fruit in a store. This will ignore all of the dictionary values youve created and only look at the model. It should be used according to the blog above when the use case is ideal.

Answer (score -3):

What @data_henrik answered was partially correct. But it doesn't seem like Watson Assistant "**automatically**" learns the preferred `@Entity` just by simply inputting the pure (plain-text) Examples into the `#Intent`. In fact, that step was required. But we still need to do one more step.

After keying in the good plain-text Examples into the `#Intent`, we then still need to "right click" on the text-string of the possible `@Entity` entry, and then choose (teach Watson) the correct `@Entity` name from the dropdown list appeared.

Only then Watson starts to understand such; this `#Intent` uses that `@Entity`, I suppose.

[image]

Thank you @data_henrik, and appreciate your hint.

Comment: You are confusing user entities with contextual entities. They are different things. You only need to add a word from the entity from a training question and it will use the other words of that user entity to train with similar questions.  Contextual entities (what you show) is NLP entity detection.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty I didn't quite get what you mean. There is Entity section in Watson Assistant. Therefore I'm using it. Simple. If it is not correct, would you mind giving a proper Answer by potentially showing the different approach in order to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: I think the issue is more with your question. Your question talks about solving for a user entity, but your solution is a contextual entity.